# Laravel send notification as super-admin from admin controller

Tags: laravel

I have Super-Admin and Admin roles. In Admin view I've added button to request verification email. The problem I'm having is that when Admin clicks the button to receive verification email, the email is from Admin, not Super-Admin.

How to make this to be sent to Admin from Super-Admin, instead of from Admin?

Route:

```
Route::post('/dashboard/SendEmailVerification', 'AdminDashboardController@SendEmailVerification')->name('dashboard.SendEmailVerification');
```

In AdminDashboardController:

```
use App\Notifications\EmailVerification;
use App\User;
.............
public function SendEmailVerification(Request $request){
    
        $user = User::where('email_verification_code', $request->code)
          ->withoutGlobalScope('active')
          ->first();

        $user->notify(new EmailVerification($user));

        return Reply::success('Email sent!');
    }
```

And the notification email:

```
namespace App\Notifications;

use App\Traits\SmtpSettings;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use App\User;

class EmailVerification extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable, SmtpSettings;

    protected $user;
    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->setMailConfigs();
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *t('mail::layout')
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        $via = ['mail'];

        return $via;
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
            ->subject('Confirm your email')
            ->greeting(__('Hello!'))
            ->line(__('email.emailVerify.text'))
            ->action('Confirm', getDomainSpecificUrl(route('front.get-email-verification', $this->user->email_verification_code), $this->user->company));
            #->line(__('email.thankyouNote'));
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return $notifiable->toArray();
    }

}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "How to make this to be sent to Admin from Super-Admin, instead of from Admin?". Whats the error in your case, wrong sender email, wrong name in email template, or something else?

Comment: Wrong sender email and name. The email is from the Admin user and not from SuperAdmin user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting wrong sender address because you never defined who's the sender in your Notification configuration. There are two ways to do this:

**First**: The first one is a really simple, but non-dynamic solution. In your .env configuration config, add these lines:

```
MAIL_FROM_NAME="My Name"
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=support@example.com
```

When you configure this, add this in yout config/mail.php configuration:

```
 'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'default value if not found in .env'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'default value if not found in .env'),
    ],
```

*Note: Don't forget to clear your cache, and restart queue when you do this:*

**Second**: This is a more dynamic solution, since you can load the sender email address from your database. In your `SendEmailVerification` method, you can query up the super-admin user, and pass to the `EmailVerification` class:

```
public function SendEmailVerification(Request $request){
    
        $user = User::where('email_verification_code', $request->code)
          ->withoutGlobalScope('active')
          ->first();

        $superAdminUser = User::where('role', 'super-admin')->first();

        $user->notify(new EmailVerification($user, $superAdminUser));

        return Reply::success('Email sent!');
    }
```

Then, change your EmailVerification class:

```
public $user;
public $superUser; 
public function __construct(User $user, User $superUser)
{
    $this->user = $user;
    $this->superUser = $superUser;
    $this->setMailConfigs();
}
```

And in your `toMail()` method, add another `from()` method:

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
        ->subject('Confirm your email')
        ->from($superAdminUser->email, $superAdminUser->first_name)
        ->greeting(__('Hello!'))
        ->line(__('email.emailVerify.text'))
        ->action('Confirm', getDomainSpecificUrl(route('front.get-email-verification', $this->user->email_verification_code), $this->user->company));
        #->line(__('email.thankyouNote'));
}
```

*Note: Also clear your cache and restart your queue.*

Hope that this can resolve your issue. Let me know if you have any problems with these solutions.

You can read more about notifications on [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/notifications).